# Why did both Nadav and Avihu go up?

Tags: kohen-priest, parashas-yisro, bechor-firstborn, har-sinai

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99139/why-did-only-nadav-and-avihu-and-not-their-brothers-go-up-with-the-70-elders) asks why didn't Elazar and Itamar go up Har Sinai like Nadav and Avihu. I'm wondering why **both** Nadav and Avihu went up.

There's a [disagreement](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.19.22?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) who were the kohanim that went up the mountain. Per the view that says  that they were the first-born, shouldn't just Nadav have gone up?

Comment: Were all the Zekeinim either kohanim or bechorim? Weren't they chosen to go up due to their standing and stature in klal Yisroel? If so, Nadav and Avihu would be the same.

Comment: @Chatzkel Chizkuni, at least, wrote that all of the elders were firstborn. So what was Nadav and Avihu's stature? If they were elders, shouldn't they just be included in the number 70? And does that mean that Elazar and Itamar weren't elders?

Comment: In the end of Ki Sisa where Rashi discusses the system of teaching from Moshe Rabbeinu he says Aron first, then the Bnei Aron, then the Zekinim, then the rest of Klal Yisroel . So it seems that Bnei Aron were "on top" of the Zekeinim not part of them

Comment: R' A"L Shteinman in Ayeles Hashachar suggests that Elazar and Isamar were not considered as chashuv while Nadav and Avihu were alive

Comment: @Chatzkel did he give a reason for this?

Comment: He mentions it as the reason they did not go up on Har Sinai

Comment: @Chatzkel I meant, does he explain why Elazar and Itamar were less important than Nadav and Avihu?

Comment: No. He just mentions it without elaboration